# How to fix NameError: Java error in HecDSS Python Script

Tags: python, java

I'm working on reading and writing information in HecDSS. I had this script working fine last night except when I opened it this morning I began getting this error:

```
    ScriptEngine.execute:Error in script Traceback (innermost last):
      File "<string>", line 13, in ?
    NameError: java
```

The basic code I'm using now is:

```
    from hec.script import *
    from hec.hecmath import *
    from java import *


    try:  
      dssFile = DSS.open("C:/Documents and Settings/SWP/Desktop/MVCA.dss")
      outflow = dssFile.read("/MAITLAND VALLEY/BLYTH/PRECIP-INC/01DEC2011/30MIN/OBS/")
      newOutflow = outflow.add(10.)

      path = DSSPathname(newOutflow.getPath())
      fPart = path.fPart() + " Test"
      path.setFPart(fPart)
      newOutflow.setPathname(path.getPathname())

      dssFile.write(newOutflow)

    except java.lang.Exception, e :
       MessageBox.showError(e.getMessage(), "Error reading data")
```

I'm just trying to figure out why it doesn't work all of a sudden. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` import imports all names from the module into the local namespace. So you you do:

```
from java import *
```

And the `java` modules has a submodule called `lang`, you can access it as `lang`, not `java.lang`.

I don't know enough about Jython, but I think that you want something like this:

```
import java.lang
```

In which case you can refer to the exception as `java.lang.Exception`.

Regarding to why it worked before, it probably never raised an exception before. Now it did and it tries to catch it, but it can't find the exception type.

Comment: Although your reply wasn't exactly the fix I required, it did lead me in the right direction. I forgot to import some libs (from hec.heclib.dss import *) somehow and this fixed everything.

Comment: Then I guess it works only accidentally, because some of the imported modules has also imported `java` into its local namespace. The best advice is to stop using `from ... import *`, otherwise you will never know what do you have imported and what not.